# Column Headers in a mobile App

Tags: usability, gui-design, mobile-application

We are designing a task-oriented mobile Inspection App to be used by inspectors on the field.
Attached is the Dashboard with all inspection requests.
Is it a a good Mobile UX/UI practice to show the column headers? is this a form vs function argument? The columns also need to be filtered and sorted.

Not sure if this is a consideration, but the end user demographic is the Baby Boomers generation.

[image: Dashboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few thoughts.

#### Observe

You need to test before you leave the headings off.

#### Use labels

I've tried leaving labels off data where it should be obvious, and it's amazing how lost occasional users get. What kind of users are these? Do they use the product all day, every day?

#### Improve the layout

Have a look at your email Inbox, on a mobile device. See how it's not in tabular format, but in multi-line units? See if you can improve your layout. The most important things can have even bigger text.

#### Large print

Baby Boomers can't read small text. Watch them read, and you'll see what I mean. if they have to squint, these inspectors will avoid your product. Or if they're forced to use it, they'll come to hate it because it reinforces that they're old, every time they use it.

Comment: Thanks Jerome. Like you suggested , we will add labels to the app and take it for a spin. We are working on a new design for this and will post it here to see if we are missing anything UX-wise

Comment: Thanks. And—hey—how about an up-vote for people who took the time to reply?

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no need to show column headers if the content is clear without it.**

Leaving the headers out makes the design cleaner and allows the user to focus on key information.

In the above example, the name, address, and phone number are quite clear.  The icons are a nice hint.

It is not obvious to me what some of the other elements mean.  This may be clear to a user who knows the context of the app, however.  This is something you would have to consider carefully.

**Update:** you could still sort each column with little up and down triangles over each column, even if there were no header.  There are various ways to implement filtering, which may or may not require a column header.  Filtering could be handled in a separate part of the interface and doesn't necessarily need to be in the headers.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. How can the filter and sort icons be depicted without a column header?

Comment: @V.Kulkarni updated.

Answer (score 0):

No, Showing header unnecessarily is not a good Mobile UX/UI practice because it has small screen which must contain only relevant data.
If you will keep your head out from this design, then it will look better, clean and easy to read.
Instead of heading... Filter & sorting is a good idea.

As per my understanding FLITER & SORTING is a 2 different thing

FILTER - In this case if you have more than 2 things and want to see only one at a time then you have to use it.

SORTING - In this case if you want to see your data in a specific order, then only you have to use it